# 417 (Expectation Failed) when uploading file from angular 8, spring boot web

Tags: angular, spring-boot, file-upload, spring-rest

When I'm running in my local machine it's working fine, after deploying into dev server I'm encountering the below issue file upload failed, Reason: 417 (Expectation Failed)

The files are uploading into the project directory of path src/main/webapp/upload-dir

angular service class

```
    upload(application: JobApplication): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
{        
        var formData = new FormData();      
    ( application.prevFile ) && formData.append( "prevFile", application.prevFile );
    ( application.currFile ) && formData.append( "currFile", application.currFile );    
    console.log("Service",formData)
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', `${this.baseUrl}/upload`, formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json',        
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

Controller in Spring boot

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("prevFile") MultipartFile prevFile, @RequestParam("currFile") MultipartFile currFile) {

      String message = "";
      String filename=null;
      try {
          if ( null != prevFile && null != currFile ) {
              storageService.save(prevFile,currFile);
              filename =   switchService.fileCompareService(prevFile.getOriginalFilename(),currFile.getOriginalFilename());
              files.add(filename);
          }

        message = "File comparision completed for the input files  Previous File:" + prevFile.getOriginalFilename()+"  Current File:"+currFile.getOriginalFilename();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Could not upload the file: " + prevFile.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
      }
    }
```

Comment: spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=128KB
, spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=128KB you have these set in your application? change size as per your requirement?

Comment: are you using httpclient?

Comment: If I try to set  'Expect': '100-continue' in Header again getting "Refused to set unsafe header "Expect"

Comment: Yes, I have defined                                                                            spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=20MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=20MB                This application is working when I'm running in my local system. But if I deploy in dev server it's throwing that 417 (Expectation Failed), If I tried to set set 'Expect': '100-continue' in Header again getting "Refused to set unsafe header "Expect"

Comment: Yes, I'm using httpClient

Comment: It was resolved. Issue, I have given project resource path for upload. If I used System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"); it worked for me.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit, where did you bring the changes (System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"); which solved the issue?